# watir - installation

Tags: watir

I have installed Ruby 2, devkit & Watir.  I am getting the following error.  Can anyone please help me resolve this issue?

```
C:\devkit>irb
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
irb(main):001:0> require "watir"
=> true

irb(main):002:0> browser = Watir::Browser.new

LoadError: cannot load such file -- watir-classic
from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in`require'
from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/watir-4.0.2/lib/watir/loader.rb:48:in `load_driver'
from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/watir-4.0.2/lib/watir/loader.rb:40:in `load_driver_for'
from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/watir-4.0.2/lib/watir/loader.rb:8:in `new'
from (irb):2
from C:/Ruby200/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
irb(main):003:0>
```

Comment: Do you have watir-classic gem installed?

Comment: not specifically, i thought it would be part of the default installation?  i'll try to find that...thanks.

Comment: It should be. Maybe something has changed with Ruby 2.0. I would wait for next patch level of that version before trying that out. Just in case :)

Comment: I'm not sure what happened then, but in case someone else runs into this problem here is what i did to get it working.  Install the watir-classic (as suggested), install ffi, uninstall ffi, install ffi again.  For some reason i had 2 variations of ffi (might be due to originally installing Ruby 64 bit?), but I also uninstalled 64 bit Ruby and installed 32 bit to get this all working.

Comment: I must have missed this.  The document indicates installing operation_system.rb & devkit.rb.  I ended up getting the following thrown back pretty much instantaneous --> C:\devkit>ruby dk.rb install
[INFO] Skipping existing gem override for 'C:/Ruby200'
[WARN] Skipping existing DevKit helper library for 'C:/Ruby200'

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what happened then, but in case someone else runs into this problem here is what i did to get it working. Install the watir-classic (as suggested), install ffi, uninstall ffi, install ffi again. For some reason i had 2 variations of ffi (might be due to originally installing Ruby 64 bit?), but I also uninstalled 64 bit Ruby and installed 32 bit to get this all working. – breezy katt Feb 26 at 13:47

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're talking about using Watir on a Windows machine. From my experience installing Ruby in the correct way is the most difficult part.

First of all, install everything as if you're on a 32 bit system. The 64 bit installation often brings unwanted issues.

That said, the `ffi` gem can also cause issues, so you'll have to uninstall it, and re-install with specific tags:

```
gem uninstall ffi
gem install ffi --platform ruby
```

Finally, the error that is showing `LoadError: cannot load such file -- watir-classic` simply means that what you're doing is trying to make use of a certain gem that is not there. In this case `watir-classic`, so the following should fix that:

```
gem install watir-classic
```

[A complete guide on installing Watir on Windows](http://www.testautomation.info/Installing_ruby_with_cucumber_on_a_windows_machine)