# irb gives a LoadError: cannot load watir-classic

Tags: ruby, rubygems, watir

On my laptop with Windows 7 Ultimate, I'm following the on-line Watir primer at http://watir.github.com/watirbook/chap04.html#installation ....

I've installed ruby, devkit, watir as per instructions on the page. And this looks fine:

```
C:\Users\Afshin>ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p0 (2013-02-24) [i386-mingw32]

C:\Users\Afshin>gem -v
2.0.0
```

However, still following instruction from the online tutor page, gives me the following:

```
C:\Users\Afshin>irb
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle

irb(main):001:0> require "watir"
=> true

irb(main):002:0> browser = Watir::Browser.new
LoadError: cannot load such file -- watir-classic
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/watir-4.0.2/lib/watir/loader.rb:48:in `load_driver'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/watir-4.0.2/lib/watir/loader.rb:40:in `load_driver_for'
        from C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/watir-4.0.2/lib/watir/loader.rb:8:in `new'
        from (irb):2
        from C:/Ruby200/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

Any and all help is thoroughly appreciated!

Comment: There was a previous question with the same issue - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15078743/watir-installation

Answer (score 2):

My initial script, resulting in the mentioned error

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'watir'
require 'watir-webdriver'

b = Watir::Browser.new :ie

b.goto("http://www.google.be")
```

Removed the second line from the code

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'watir-webdriver'

b = Watir::Browser.new :ie

b.goto("http://www.google.be")
```

Now it works.
Not really a solution but a work around none the less.

I did install watir-classic gem first though. 
I haven't tested if this is really needed for the second snippet to work.

Comment: Nonetheless is a word.